# Array Wrong Value shown

Tags: java, arrays, string, average

I'm doing my project and I don't know what's wrong with my code. It'll ask you to enter #ofSubjects, Name of Subject, Name of Students, Grade for the subject inputed, **average grade per student** and the ***highest average***. The average grade per student was correct but when I listed the highest average, the value is incorrect. Sorry for my english, it's not my first language, and sorry for my question, I'm still learning. Thank you if you'll notice this. Here's the code

```
for (c=0; c<a; c++){
        System.out.print(e+ ". Name: ");
        students [c] = read.readLine();
        e++;
        for (f=0; f<b; f++){
            System.out.print("\t Grade in " +subjects[f] + ": ");
            grade [f] = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
           for (g = 0; g<b; g++ ){
                total [g] = grade[f] + grade[g];
                average [g] = total[g] / b;}          

        }
        System.out.println("Average: "+ (double)average[c] ); 
    }

    for (c=0; c<b; c++){
        System.out.print((double)average[c]+ "\n");}


/*Here's the output:

    MIDTERM EXAM: STUDENT RANKING
    Enter # of Student: 2
    Enter # of Subject: 2
    ----------------------------------
    Enter your 2 subjects:
    1. Java
    2. Phyton
---------------------------------
    1. Name: Proud
         Grade in Java: 90
         Grade in Phyton: 100
Average: 95.0
2. Name: Sone
     Grade in Java: 100
     Grade in Phyton: 65
Average: 65.0
82.0
65.0

The 82.0 should be 95.0.
*/
```

**[EDIT]** This question was answered finally in the comments! Thank you. But another problem arises, I'm trying to list all the grades I entered but it seems to be resetting everytime it loops. So if I entered two 2 subjects from 2 students, it'll just record the last 2 i entered.

Example:

```
MIDTERM EXAM: STUDENT RANKING
Enter # of Student: 2
Enter # of Subject: 2
----------------------------------
Enter your 2 subjects:
1. Java
2. Phyton
---------------------------------
1. Name: Proud
     Grade in Java: 90
     Grade in Phyton: 100
Average: 95.0
2. Name: Sone
     Grade in Java: 100
     Grade in Phyton: 65
Average: 82.5
95.0
82.5
List of Grades:
90
100
100
65
```

In my case, it just records the 3rd and 4th number which is 100 & 65. Please help.

```
List of Grades:
100
65
```

Comment: WElcome to so,  Please read [ask]. post a [mcve].  If you are not familiar how to debug your java appliction, then learning your IDE's debugger is the first thing you need to do.

Comment: i'd strongly suggest, for the sake of code readness, to use variable names with their meaning instead of a,b,c, etc.

Comment: I think thé for(g...) Is not at thé right place, thé average[g] should be set outside thé loop

Comment: Every Time you loop, g is reset to 0, it delete thé precedent result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your average array is in wrong place, should be outside of the loop

Try

```
    public void studentRanking() {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("MIDTERM EXAM: STUDENT RANKING");
        System.out.print("Enter # of Student: ");
        int noOfStudent = read.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter # of Subject: ");
        int noOfSubject = read.nextInt();

        String[] subjects = new String[noOfSubject];
        System.out.println("Enter your " + noOfSubject + " subjects: ");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfSubject; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + ". ");
            subjects[i] = read.next();
        }
        String[] students = new String[noOfStudent];
        double[] grade = new double[noOfSubject];
        double[] total = new double[noOfStudent];
        double[] average = new double[noOfStudent];
        double[] allGrades = new double[noOfStudent * noOfSubject];
        int t = 0;

        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < noOfStudent; i++, k++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ". Name: ");
            students[i] = read.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < noOfSubject; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t Grade in " + subjects[j] + ": ");
                grade[j] = read.nextDouble();
                allGrades[t++] = grade[j];
            }
            for (int g = 0; g < noOfSubject; g++) {
                total[k] += grade[g];
            }
            average[k] = total[k] / noOfSubject;
            System.out.println("Average: " + average[i]);
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < noOfStudent; c++) {
            System.out.println(average[c]);
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MIDTERM EXAM: STUDENT RANKING
Enter # of Student: 2
Enter # of Subject: 2
Enter your 2 subjects: 
1. Java
2. Python
1. Name: Proud
     Grade in Java: 90
     Grade in Python: 100
Average: 95.0
2. Name: Sone
     Grade in Java: 100
     Grade in Python: 65
Average: 82.5
95.0
82.5
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. But I'm trying to get all the values of grades but it seems to be resetting everytime it loops so if I enter two 2 grades for 2 students (90, 100 & 100, 65), it'll just record the last 2 value i entered (100, 65) but not the first two. Can you help me? Thank youuu.

Comment: Just declare a new array and store the grade values while saving the current grades.

Comment: Is it because of noOfSubjects? If I input 2, it'll loop just 2x but I had to input 4 grades? So when I get the list of grades, it just show 2 of them? I tried adding another array but it still gives me any 2 of the 4 i entered.

Comment: after `average[]` array decleartion add
`double[] allGrades = new double[noOfStudent * noOfSubject];
int t = 0;`

and after `grade[j] = read.nextDouble();`
Add `allGrades[t++] = grade[j];`